How should I choose an amplifier for a QRP radio?
Call is KB0STG, got General less than a year ago.
I have 2 HF rigs, Xiegu G90 (best I could afford at the time), and after insurance paid out after I had a heart attack in June, I got an IC-705. I love POTA and my townhouse is a faraday cage due to all the stucco/chicken wire, I need to get away from the house to get a less noisy floor.
Since I spent the money on the 705 and a tuner, I'm not sure what I should do next. Because of the noise floor adn HOA at my QTH, getting a 100W rig itself seems like overkill. I have to use portable antennas at home anyway, since the HOA manager is a pain.
I thought getting a good 100W amplifier would be a better next step, something that I would be able to use while RVing, camping trips (I do a bit of car camping too), and other travel. I'm just not sure what to do. Since I have a G90, the Xiegu 100W with the built in tuner sounds like a plan. I have the CE-19, so that would work out of the box, and interfaces for the 705 seem available on eBay and other sites.
Does the collective mind here have suggestions or further clarifications I haven't thought about?

By the way, a heart attack sounds like painful business – all the best, get and be well!

You could buy a 100W amp, but unless you buy a cheap amp (possibly in a kit form) from AliExpress or eBay, the amp itself will cost about the same money as FT891 or used TS590 (or one of many other quality used options). I find it easier to handle a 100W transceiver than a 5W transceiver plus amp in the field. You'll have to deal with extra power wire, more setup/cleanup time, more connectors that could potentially break, etc. So, I would consider a 100W transceiver as an option when shopping for an amp.
Also, 5W or 10W CW with a good antenna (e.g. full size vertical with elevated radials) can make a lot of contacts today, especially if you do CW or FT8.

I own a G90 and have experience with Xiegu's latest 100W linear amplifier, the XPA-125b. In may ways, I loved the amp. The automatic band-switching worked flawlessly, for example.
Unfortunately I had to return it the day after I received it. The problem was that, even with ALC all hooked up, the G90's power turned down to 1W, and my PC's volume turned down to 1, the amp would quickly go over power when transmitting FT8 data and halt transmission to protect itself.
I did a little bit of research, and I saw that beginning in early 2024 people started reporting this issue. One guy in particular had talked to Xiegu and discovered that a design change had replaced the original MOSFETs doing the heavy lifting with a single, presumably cheaper MOSFET, and that as a result the gain attained by the amp had gone from ~13dB to more like 21dB. That's a number which matched what I was seeing pretty closely, so, after some initial skepticism, I've come to believe the MOSFET change explanation.
I ordered the amp from Radioddity, so returning it was no problem. I don't want to completely say "don't get the XPA-125b," particularly if you don't care about FT8. Another thing to consider is that I was using a Xiegu DE-19, not a CE-19. I bought a special extra cable to hook everything up, but maybe the amp just works better with the CE-19. If you do give the XPA-125b a shot, I would suggest getting it from Radioddity.
The morning after I'd unboxed and then given up on the XPA-125b, I felt bummed out and also wanted to confirm that my "barefoot" G90 still worked. So, I decided to work a little SSB, and within an hour I'd made a phone contact from Atlanta, GA to Australia. That's about as far away from me as you can place an antenna on dry land.
Any desire to own an XPA-125b (even a working one) left me at that point. A linear amp is frankly a bit of a headache. My perception is that using one, even a really good one, makes the operating experience more complicated and less enjoyable. I love my G90 as-is.
I do look at amps from time to time. If I bought a "nice" amp, like an Ameritron or Elecraft "legal limit" amp, presumably it would not try to blow itself up like the XPA-125b... if I got it all wired up right: band-switching (I think this is based on voltage level conventions on an interface wire), ALC (not sure what the conventions are there, but it has to be voltage levels on a DC line, I think), and so on. It's a bit of a project. What I liked about the XPA-125b was that this stuff was supposed to be figured out for you.
So I can't snap my fingers and get either one of us 100W. Unfortunately (like most of ham radio) there's nothing plug-and-play here. Frankly the most tempting option to me seems to be to buy one of the old-design (pre-2024?) XPA-125b units second-hand.
